# PanacheEntityBase setting by default id as not nullable, even if specifying the reverse

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have an java class set as entity, which is defined as follow:

```java
package com.redhat.bvbackend.player;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntityBase;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import com.redhat.bvbackend.team.Team;


@Entity
public class Player extends PanacheEntityBase {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "player_id", nullable = true)
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "playerSequence", sequenceName = "playerIdSequence", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "playerSequence")
  public Long id;

  public String name;

  public String familyName;

  public int age;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "name", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
  public List<Team> teams;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 1, max = 1, message = "Handed must be either Left or Right")
  public String handed;

}
```

My class extends PanacheEntityBase and I am setting the column to allow nullable entries, and I am creating a generator to automatically increment the player_id for each new entry. My thought is that if a generator is defined, I shouldn't need to set the nullable since the generator already have an initialValue specified. Actually if I see the @column reference or not, it doesn't change I get always the same output. See below.

[image]

I would like to create an player as follow:

```sql
INSERT INTO player (age,familyname,handed,name) VALUES (25,'foo','x','y');
```

without the need to specify the id. However when I do so I get:

> ```
> ERROR:  null value in column "player_id" violates not-null constraint
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 25, foo, x, y).
> ```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no "generator" though is there? The "Default" in that table definition is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Though you have a sequence generator created for that ID as `playerIdSequence` your column does not have a default value set.

The `@GeneratedValue` itself will be used within the panache insert sequence itself, and it will set the value of the ID when building the SQL request.

If you want to be able to automatically assign your ID when running raw SQL requests to the database yourself, you should assign a default value to something like `nextval('playerIdSequence')`. This way, it will get the next number in the sequence.

You can change the table like this:

```
alter table public.player alter column player_id set default nextval('playerIdSequence');
```